# Can we use IntStream#sum, If sum of elements is greater than the Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Tags: java, java-stream

What happens when the sum of elements in a stream is greater than the  `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

```
int sum = IntStream.of(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1).sum();
```

In my computer this returns, `-(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1)`   -> `-2147483648`

So when should one not use `java.util.stream.IntStream#sum`?

Comment: When one cares about the correctness of the result and suspects that the sum might overflow. Just like when you do any other operation involving integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int + int` does the same thing. This problem is not with `sum()` but rather you are using a type which is too limited.

```
long sum = IntStream.of(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1)
        .asLongStream()
        .sum();
System.out.println(sum);
```

prints

```
2147483648
```

All data types have limitations and you need to be aware of these when using them.  You could argue that it would be better for an error to be produced rather than silently giving an unexpected result, but that is not how the types have been implemented.

Comment: Instead of `.mapToLong(i->i)`, use `.asLongStream()`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use IntStream#sum if you can either guarantee that your values will not exceed the maximum integer value or you handle the overflow in the code. Otherwise, you can use LongStream, e.g.`System.out.println(LongStream.of(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1).sum());`

Answer (score 2):

whenever any integers crosses the max value it starts counting from the lower bound of integers.
for ex: if u write Integer.MAX_VAlUE+10 it will give u -2147483639.
so here,
jvm started counted with 0 to the max value of integer and then after reaching the max value it started counting form (-2147483648,-2147483647,...upto -2147483639)